# Map a key press to a button click in Gtk Python

Tags: python, button, gtk

I want a key press to be mapped with a button click function in Gtk-python, i.e. if `Enter` key is pressed, the `data-process` function should execute, which is called by pressing the `process` button.

Can this be done?

Comment: You have not given sufficient information to solve the problem. For example, which widget has the focus while Enter is being pressed?

Comment: The thing is , when you commented, you have 2 choices: either press the enter key, or click the `Add comment` button. so, both actions call the same function.I want to do a similar thing in my app

Comment: In that analogy, the choice of pressing "enter" is available only while the comment text area is focused. The question is, which widget is focused in your application? A GtkEntry, a GtkTextView, or something else?

Comment: Why don't you consider adding [`key-press-event`](http://pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#signal-gtkwidget--key-press-event) or `key-release-event` and check the event passed to the callback for `Enter` key and call your button click function? As mentioned by user4815162342 key events are sent to the current focus widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speculating this might a `Gtk.Dialog`, you can set the default response.

[**`gtk_dialog_set_default_response ()`**](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkDialog.html#gtk-dialog-set-default-response):

> Sets the last widget in the dialog's action area with the given response_id as the default widget for the dialog. Pressing "Enter" normally activates the default widget.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a gtk.Entry() and a gtk.Button(), I think what you need to do is just connecting the gtk.Entry() to your data-process function like this:

    `b = gtk.Button("Process")
    b.connect("clicked", data-process)
    e = gtk.Entry()
    e.connect("activate", data-process)`

That should do the "Trick".

Hope this helped.